# Umount Gamepad under Mac OS X

Tags: usb, virtualization

I can plug in my gamepad controller and usb probe shows me, that it is recognized. I want to umount it, so that I can use it under the Virtualbox. Where does Mac mount USB devices such as a gamepad.

Here is a picture of the usb probe output:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be able to configure VB to share USB devices. Is that not working?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I installed some updates today and now its working. But still I do not know where it is mounted under Mac (in Ubuntu I can look under /dev/input to see, if its mounted).